# Error with controls command in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I created 2 forms. form1 contains 2 textbox, form2 contains 2 textbox, and 1 commandbutton. 
this code does not work. how to write the right one?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim nom As String
nom = UserForm2.TextBox2
UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & nom) = UserForm2.TextBox1
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

form1:

```
Private Sub textbox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
form2.show
form2.textbox2=1
End Sub
Private Sub textbox2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
form2.show
form2.textbox2=2
End Sub
```

form2:

```
Private Sub commandbutton_click()
unload me
Dim nom As String
    nom = UserForm2.TextBox2
    UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & nom) = UserForm2.TextBox1
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works for me.  So I guess that means it is already "the right one".  (At least, it is until you give some clue as to why you don't think it is doing what you want it to do.)

Comment: my complete writing update above

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.  Are you saying that the only possible description you can provide of what isn't working is what you have already written in the question, i.e. "this code does not work"?

Comment: what I am doing i re-update above

Comment: The `Unload Me` that you added between your original question and the edited question is going to cause problems.  Once form2 is unloaded, how do you expect to access what the user had entered into the Textboxes?

Comment: And I am guessing that you really want to update the value of `form2.textbox2` **before** you do `form2.Show` - there doesn't seem to be much point updating the value **after** you have unloaded the form following the user clicking the button.

Comment: But all my comments are pure conjecture - what do **you** believe is not working?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @DavidG. find the way of writing for code not error

Comment: @YowE3K.does the above code run normally when you run it?

Comment: If I remove the `Unload Me` (or move it until after finishing the processing) and I ignore the fact that the `form2.textbox2=1` and `form2.textbox2=2` statements are pointless, yes, the code works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve but try with:

form1:

```
Private Sub textbox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  form2.show
  form2.textbox2.Value = "1"
End Sub

Private Sub textbox2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  form2.show
  form2.textbox2.Value = "2"
End Sub
```

form2:

```
Private Sub commandbutton_click()
  Dim nom As String
    nom = me.TextBox2.Value
    UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & nom).Value = UserForm2.TextBox1.Value
  unload me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

solved.

form1

```
Private Sub TextBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Unload Me
UserForm2.TextBox2 = 1
UserForm2.Show
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Unload Me
UserForm2.TextBox2 = 2
UserForm2.Show
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
TextBox1 = Cells(2, 2)
TextBox2 = Cells(3, 2)
End Sub
```

form2

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error Resume Next
Dim nom As String
nom = TextBox2
UserForm1.Controls("textbox" & nom) = UserForm2.TextBox1
Cells(nom + 1, 2) = UserForm2.TextBox1
Unload Me
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```